# How can i translate custom elements in .phtml file according to store view

Tags: magento2, cart, phtml, store-view, multi-language

I have added a  tag in form.phtml file which shows on view Cart Page.

```
<h1>Custom Cart Information</h1>
```

which effects as
[image]

Hence my store is multi-lingual when i change store view to japanese
title SHOPPING CART is getting translated but CUSTOM CART INFORMATION  is printing is in english 
[image]

I want this CUSTOM CART INFORMATION tag to be translated whenever i change my store view.
Is there any way to do this.

Comment: check your theme has ---   i18n

this folder

Comment: can you give me path so i can check?? exactly where i18n folder is located in a theme

Comment: I have checked in app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/ there is no i18n folder here but the file in which im editing magento/module-checkout has i18n folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i have got solution for this.

**Step 1**
If you want to translate that tag write in magento format like this.

```
<h1><label class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Custom Cart Information')) ?></label></h1>
```

**Step 2**

Add that phrase in your module's i18n/lang_country.csv in my case it is magento_root/vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n/en_US.csv

Add this phrase at the end of csv file in two columns.
[image]

**Step 3**

Find the csv file of your language package in my case path of language pack's csv file is magento_root/vendor/magento-2-japanese-language-pack/ja_JP.csv

Now add translation for your phrase at the end of csv.you have to add 3 columns as
English Phrase || Japanese Phrase || Module Name

Add a row like this
[image]
If you dont want to specify the module just write lib and web and dont know the translation of phrase refer google translate.

**Step 4**

Now, run indexer:reindex cache:flush command and refresh the page.
you will see output like this.
[image]
I hope it will work for everyone.

it will only work in the custom text changing .. if you want to change the in-build text changing which already registered in magento transaction, then you have to override .csv file in theme..

Answer (score 1):

> you need to create that folder
>
> explained in this doc
>
> plz refer
>
> also try with your activated theme folder

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/theme_dictionary.html